# Name or service not known in gcp cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to gcp. after i log into vm-2 through ssh shell,can not able to ping or enter the vm-1. the error message appears: "Name or service not known". but i am able to ping it through ip address. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the FQDN of the VM and not just the hostname/vm-name.

Example: **VM_NAME.ZONE.c.PROJECT_ID.internal**

[Google Cloud Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns)